# PHP check if ID already is in use

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently busy with creating my own 6 player game based on PHP/MySQL. I want to check if the ID from players_online is already in use, if yes then it need to keep searching until it found one (till max 6) else it need to return 0;

$con is the connection to the database and you can find the settings on the .mysql_config.php

This is what I got:

```
function find_local_id()
{
    include'./mysql_config.php';
    $i=1;
    $select_id=mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `ID` FROM `players_online` WHERE ID = ".$i.""));
    if ($select_id["ID"] == $i) {
        $i++;
        $select_id=mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `ID` FROM `players_online` WHERE ID = ".$i.""));
        if ($select_id["ID"] == $i) {
            $i++;
            $select_id=mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `ID` FROM `players_online` WHERE ID = ".$i.""));
            if ($select_id["ID"] == $i) {
                $i++;
                $select_id=mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `ID` FROM `players_online` WHERE ID = ".$i.""));
                if ($select_id["ID"] == $i) {
                    $i++;
                    $select_id=mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `ID` FROM `players_online` WHERE ID = ".$i.""));
                    if ($select_id["ID"] == $i) {
                        $i++;
                        $select_id=mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `ID` FROM `players_online` WHERE ID = ".$i.""));
                        if ($select_id["ID"] == $i) {
                            return 0;
                        } else {
                            return 6;
                        }
                    } else {
                        return 5;
                    }
                } else {
                    return 4;
                }
            } else { 
                return 3;
            }
        } else { 
            return 2;
        }
    } else { 
        return 1;
    }
```

Is there a way to have this smaller/compact? Because I think this is pretty big for just a small function. :)

Comment: Holy..... You could probably combine *all that* into a nice, single database call.

Comment: How about doing a query that will see which of players 0-6 are online, instead of all those separate queries?

Comment: It would be more efficient to make one select/fetch to MySQL and pull up a list of all the player ID's, and then sort them out using a PHP script.  How many players are you anticipating?

Comment: @Shomz Haha... But how :) I am just a beginner with using PHP/MySQL

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here but assuming sequential ID's in a database seems like a dangerous idea.

Comment: Many many ways to check if a user exists. What did Google say?

Comment: Holy mother of if statements... why are you doing this? why not just use a few OR statements in one SELECT???

Comment: So will there always only be a single game available? I would think you would need the concept of a game and the concept of game players which are related to games at a minimum. What happens when a game ends? It just disappears into the ether?

Comment: How? By referencing any login system built by a sane and experienced programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would work:

```
function find_local_id()
{
    include'./mysql_config.php';

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `ID` FROM `players_online`");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $ids[] = $row['ID'];
    }
    if($available = array_diff(range(0, 6), $ids)) {
        return min($available);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you have `mysqli_fetch_all` use that.

1. Get all of the IDs in the table
2. See which ones (1-6) are not in the results
3. If any are available return the lowest one
4. If not return 0

Comment: In this case `$ids` would only hold one record since you never looped through the result set.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Thank you for this answer, but what if all ID's are in use... how can I then return 0;?

Comment: Sorry, keeps getting longer and longer.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Haha, I really appreciate your help :) But I just keep getting a Array to string conversion at the  "if($available = array_diff(range(0, 6), $ids)) {" line :/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you could use a loop to do this (but you don't need one).

You're hitting the DB many times unnecessarily.

Create a function or query (like the one below) that accepts one integer id and returns the count of rows.

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourdb', 'user', 'pass');

$id = ''; //input, whether it be a param from a function, session superglobal, GET or POST.

$exists = $db->prepare('SELECT id FROM players_online WHERE id = ?');
$exists->execute(array($id));

echo $exists->rowCount(); // if greater than 1 or equal, it exists.
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd be far better off doing something like

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM players_online WHERE id BETWEEN {$i} AND {$i}+6";
$stmt = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$in_use = mysqli_num_rows($stmt);
```

If all 6 IDs are in the database, then you'll get 6 rows in `$in_use`. If 5 show up, then you'll get 5 rows, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a really flawed design in that you are never going to scale for more than one game at at time with this approach, are going to need to delete rows from your table to make it work when generating a new game, and are going to have problems with race conditions in cases where concurrency is high. But assuming you have a means for managing inserting player record id's in order (1,2,3, etc.).  Your query can simply be:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM players_online
```

This will tell you the current highest id in the table. You would simply insert the next player with the id value incremented by 1 above the current max value.